# is it possible to use GQL from a java appengine application?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is it possible to use GQL from a java appengine application?

I've seen several references to GqlQuery object in various packages here and there, but I see nothing about how to use it from an AppEngine application.

Is it possible? What maven package should I use for it? If it's available, is it stable -or- pre-release?

Thanks, Chad

Comment: Why would you want to use it? It can make it more difficult to think in SQL-terms about a non-relational database.

Comment: Because it's much easier/smaller/cleaner to write and execute a query than to write things in terms of an AST...?

Comment: Look at the libraries that have been specifically designed for the Datastore, like Objectify.

Comment: Andrei - great pointer - I will have a more detailed look.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible. I did some googling and I have noted here what I found.

**Disclaimer: I have tested none of this and I, like Andrei, would strongly recommend using Objectify.**

You can get a datastore instance from the API. From https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/datastore-api-tutorial:

```
// Create an authorized Datastore service using Application Default Credentials.
private final Datastore datastore = DatastoreOptions.defaultInstance().service();
```

You would need at least the following Maven package. Like it says it is in Beta.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-datastore-protobuf</artifactId>
    <version>v1beta2-rev1-4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You could then do a GQL query like this.
From https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/gql:

```
// import static com.google.api.services.datastore.client.DatastoreHelper.*;

GqlQuery.Builder query = GqlQuery.newBuilder().setQueryString("SELECT * FROM Person");
RunQueryRequest request = RunQueryRequest.newBuilder().setGqlQuery(query).build();

RunQueryResponse response = datastore.runQuery(request);
List<Entity> results = new ArrayList<Entity>();
for (EntityResult entityResult : response.getBatch().getEntityResultList()) {
  results.add(entityResult.getEntity());
}
```

Comment: I assume this is correct -- but I'm not sure if it's "legal" from a GAE project. I'm a bit surprised people don't ask for this more often. I must be missing something from the picture. Thanks for the details - I'll give it a try here soon and report back.